# searching an integer from a text file in c

Tags: c, search, full-text-search, type-conversion, readfile

I have a simulation program written in c and I need to create random numbers and write them to a txt file. Program only stops 
- when a random number already generated is generated again or
- 1 billion random number are generated (no repetition)

My problem is that I could not search the generated long int random number in the txt file!
Text file format is:
9875
764
19827
2332
...
Any help is appreciated..
`

```
FILE * out;

int checkNumber(long int num){
    char line[512];
    long int number;  
    int result=0; 

    if((out = fopen("out.txt","r"))==NULL){
            result= 1;
    }

    char buf[10];
    itoa(num, buf, 10);


    while(fgets(line, 512, out) != NULL)
    {
       if((strstr(line,buf)) != NULL){
              result = 0;
       }
    }
    if(out) {
        fclose(out);
    } 
    return result;  
}


int main(){
    int seed;
    long int nRNs=0;
    long int numberGenerated;     
    out = fopen ("out.txt","w");

    nRNs=0;
    seed = 12345;

    srand (seed);  

    fprintf(out,"%d\n",numberGenerated);
    while( nRNs != 1000000000 )
    {
      numberGenerated = rand();
      nRNs++;

      if(checkNumber(numberGenerated)==0){
          fclose(out); break; system("pause"); 
      }
      else{
          fprintf(out,"%d\n",numberGenerated);
      }

    }    

    fclose(out);
```

}`

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: what did you try? why you can't find it what did you do wrong? show some code

Answer (score 1):

If the text file only contains randomly generated numbers separated by space, then you need `strtok()` function(google its usage) and throw it into the binary tree structure as mentioned by @jacekmigacz. But in any circumstance, you **will** have to search the whole file once at least. Then `ftell()` the value to get the location you've searched for in the file. When another number is generated you can use `fseek()` to get the latest number. Remember to get the data line by line with `fgets()`

Take care of the memory requirements and use `malloc()` judiciously

Answer (score 0):

Try with [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29) (data structure).

Comment: How can that be helpful anyway? he will have to search sequentially for all numbers already in the txt file

Comment: Could you be more specific about using a tree structure?

Comment: Linear search for duplicate would be slow. Organizing numbers as tree will be fast. O(n) vs O(log n) (for RB-tree).

Answer (score 0):

Searching linearly through the text file every time is gonna take forever with so many numbers. You could hold every number generated so far sorted in a data structure so that you can do a binary search for a duplicate. This is going to need a lot of RAM though. For 1 billion integers that's already 4GB on a  system with 32-bit integers, and you'll need several more for the data structure overhead. My estimate is around 16GB in the worst case scenario (where you actually get to 1 billion unique integers.)

If you don't have a memory monster machine, you should instead write the data structure to a binary file and do the binary search there. Though that's still gonna be quite slow.

Answer (score 0):

This may work or you can approach like this : (slow but will work)

```
  int new_rand = rand();
    static int couter = 0;
    FILE *fptr = fopen("txt","a+");
    int i;
    char c,buf[10];
    while((c=getc(fptr))!=EOF)
    {
     buf[j++]=c;
     if(c == ' ')
       {
        buf[--j]='\0';
        i=atoi(buf);
        if(i == new_rand)
           return;
        j=0;
    }
    if(counter < 1000000)
   {
    fwrite(&new_rand, 4, 1, fptr);
    counter++;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't open and scan your file to `checkNumber()`.  You'll be waiting forever.

Instead, keep your generated numbers in memory using a [bit set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array) data structure and refer to that.

Your bit set will need to be large enough to indicate every 32-bit integer, so it'll consume `2^32 / 8` bytes (or `512MiB`) of memory.  This may seem like a lot but it's much smaller than `32-bit * 1,000,000,000` (`4GB`).  Also, both checking and updating will be done in constant time.

Edit: The wikipedia link doesn't do much to explain how to code one, so here's a rough sample:  (There're faster ways of writing this, e.g.: using bit shifts instead of division, but this should be easier to understand.)

```
int checkNumberOrUpdate(char *bitSet, long int num){
    char b = 1 << (num % 8);
    char w = num / 8;

    if (bitSet[w] & ~b) {
        return 1;
    }
    bitSet[w] |= b;
    return 0;
}
```

Note, `bitSet` needs to be `calloc()`d to the right size from your main function.